# Error "Image.clipToBoundsAndScale: Projection error when constructing output region: Can't transform (-180.0,-90.0)" When trying to export to drive

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have the following code in the Google Earth Engine. This code divides the earth into parts and then exports them to Google Drive:

```
var dataset = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global/2019")
.select('discrete_classification');

Map.addLayer(dataset,{}, 'Land Cover');

// This code divides the earth into parts and then exports them to Google Drive
var nParts = 8;
var ndParts = nParts / 2;

var unit = 360 / nParts;
for (var amp = 0; amp < nParts; amp++) {
    for (var alt = 0; alt < ndParts; alt++){
      
      var polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
        [(amp * unit)       - 180 , alt *       unit - 90 ],
        [((amp + 1) * unit) - 180 , alt *       unit - 90 ],
        [(amp * unit)       - 180 , (alt + 1) * unit - 90 ],
        [((amp + 1) * unit) - 180 , (alt + 1) * unit - 90 ],
        ]);
        
        var fileName = 'earth_data_' + String(amp)+ '_' + String(alt);
        
        
      Export.image.toDrive({
        image: dataset,
        scale: 500,
        folder: 'EE_exports',
        fileNamePrefix: fileName,
        region: polygon,
        maxPixels: 1000000000,
        
      });
          
    }
}
```

And when i try to download the file called `earth_data_0_0` from the tasks panel I got this error:

> "Error: Image.clipToBoundsAndScale: Projection error when constructing
> output region: Can't transform (-180.0,-90.0) (Error code: 3)"

This seems to happen especially in images with some boundary with -180, 180, -90, 90, how could I solve this or what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your polygons are not well formed.  But also, just avoid the poles.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem, it was quite simple to solve, the problem in the first place is that i was trying to divide the world by dividing the coordinates of 360 and 180 total degrees and using the range of 360 -> (+180 to -180) and 180 -> (+90 to -90) with just resting 180 and 90 in the code but, that's incorrect for the current coordinate system used by default in the google earth engine, so to solve the problem i just need to change the coord system used when exporting to drive

so just to fix the code, it's needed to add one line of code, the correct code is:

```
var dataset = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global/2019")
.select('discrete_classification');

Map.addLayer(dataset,{}, 'Land Cover');

// This code divides the earth into parts and then exports them to Google Drive
var nParts = 8;
var ndParts = nParts / 2;

var unit = 360 / nParts;
for (var amp = 0; amp < nParts; amp++) {
    for (var alt = 0; alt < ndParts; alt++){
      
      var polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
        [(amp * unit)       - 180 , alt *       unit - 90 ],
        [((amp + 1) * unit) - 180 , alt *       unit - 90 ],
        [(amp * unit)       - 180 , (alt + 1) * unit - 90 ],
        [((amp + 1) * unit) - 180 , (alt + 1) * unit - 90 ],
        ]);
        
        var fileName = 'earth_data_' + String(amp)+ '_' + String(alt);
        
        
      Export.image.toDrive({
        image: dataset,
        scale: 500,
        folder: 'EE_exports',
        fileNamePrefix: fileName,
        region: polygon,
        maxPixels: 1000000000,
        crs: "EPSG:4326" // <------ the new line of code
      });
          
    }
}
```